# Git hotfix merging to master and master to develop

Tags: git, merge

If I have two branches: *master* and *develop*. All the releases come from the *master* branch and all features are developed from the *develop* branch.

If I create a *hotfix* branch from master and then merge it back to master I think I have two options from there:

1. Merge to master and then to develop
2. Merge to master and master to develop

My question is what is the difference and what kind of problems I might have going with either one?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In theory, there should be absolutely no difference.

Once you've merged the `hotfix` branch in to `master`, `master` and the tip of the `hotfix` branch are at exactly the same point.

So whether you merge `master` or `hotfix` in to `develop`, you end up with the same outcome.

Having said that, I personally think you should go with option 1.

With `master` being for release only, I feel you should never merge from `master` back in to `develop`, only from `develop` in to `master`.

Keeping this flow one way helps keep things in order. You know in your head you can't make any changes directly on `master`, as you won't have a way of getting them back in to `develop`. You either have to `hotfix` and merge in to both, or create a feature on `develop`.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Fair enough, I agree with you on that but in my head I see it more as a waterfall when changes propagate down from master to develop and from develop to feature but I guess it's more of a mindset. :D

But at the end of the day both methods should work and there should not be any different conflicts between the two types of merging?

Comment: As far as I'm aware, no. Both are valid methods of merging, and I've done both in different projects with no detrimental effects. As long as you're consistent within the scope of your project it doesn't matter.